# Magento 2 What method should I use instead of deprecated getCollection when fetching data from custom database table?

Tags: magento2, collection, factory

I created a custom database table and now want to fetch data, but getCollection method is deprecated and I can't find any other method that suits my case. Here's the example of my code:

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory;
use <MyName>\<MyModule>\Model\UserUpdateFactory;
```

class CustomerChangeTracker
{

```
private $customer;

private $previousCustomer;

private $current = [];


public function __construct(CollectionFactory $customer, UserUpdateFactory $previousCustomer)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
    $this->previousCustomer = $previousCustomer;
}

public function getChangesSinceLastTime(): array
{
    $current = [];
    $collection = $this->customer->create();
    foreach ($collection as $customer) {
        $current[$customer->getId()] = $customer->getData('updated_at');
    }
    $this->setCurrent($current);

    $previous = [];
    foreach ($this->previousCustomer->create()->getCollection() as $customer) {
        $previous[$customer->getData('customer_id')] = $customer->getData('updated_at');
    }
```

Comment: you shouldnt need to add the getCollection as $this->previousCustomer->create() is doing that already

Comment: did you create resourcemodel and model for your custom table?

Comment: Yes, I did create Resource Model and Model.

Comment: Thank you all, I realized I was using model factory, not collection factory. Now everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call getCollection on a collection factory class. Because as the name says it is already a collection. Alternatively you could use the resource model and call the collection from it.